# Program to check the area of a triangle if it can or can not be computed based on the sides entered. Python-3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

This program inputs three integers as side lengths of a triangle and print the area of the triangle.  If the sides cannot form a triangle, it prints an appropriate message.

The problems I have include:

- When I enter invalid lengths, such as 1 2 3, I get an area of 0.0 instead of the error message.
- When I enter a negative number, I get a math domain error instead of the error message.

Help?

```
#This program will check to see if the area of the triangle can or can not be computed based on the sides entered.

import math
while True:
     try:
         side1 = int(input("Please enter the value of side 1: "))
         side2 = int(input("Please enter the value of side 2: "))
         side3 = int(input("Please enter the value of side 3: "))
     except ValueError:
         print("Please enter a value next time instead of a letter.")
         continue
     else:
         break

def isValid(side1, side2, side3):
     if (side1 + side2 > side3) or (side1 + side3 > side2) or (side1 + side3 > side2):
         return True
     else:
         return False

def area(side1, side2, side3):
     if isValid(side1, side2, side3) is True:
         sides = (side1 + side2 + side3) / 2
         TriArea = math.sqrt(sides * (sides - side1) * (sides - side2) * (sides - side3))
         print("The area of triangle with sides", side1, side2, side3, "is", TriArea)
     elif isValid(side1, side2, side3) is False:
         print("Please enter numbers that will make a triangle.")

area(side1, side2, side3)
```

Edit: Upon changing a few things thanks to your responses it now works correctly.

After changing

```
if (side1 + side2 > side3) or (side1 + side3 > side2) or (side1 + side3 > side2):
```

to the below allowed the program to run much better.

```
if (side1 + side2 > side3) and (side1 + side3 > side2) and (side1 + side3 > side2):
```

Also changing

```
if isValid(side1, side2, side3) is True:
```

to instead the below made it much simpler.

```
if isValid(side1, side2, side3):
```

Thank you for the quick responses everyone! :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
In particular, please supply actual failing examples *and* **full** error messages, rather than making us guess what inputs will trip up your program.

Comment: Don't use `is` to check values: `if isValid(...) is True:` is wrong and can fail randomly.

Comment: doing area(3,4,5) worked for me on python2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The critical problem is your test for the triangle inequality:

```
 if (side1 + side2 > side3) or (side1 + side3 > side2) or (side1 + side3 > side2):
```

Your logic is wrong: you need all three of these to be true for a triangle to form, not just one.

```
 if (side1 + side2 > side3) and (side1 + side3 > side2) and (side2 + side3 > side1):
     # Note the change in the last clause: you made one test twice, and skipped the third.
```

will fix most of your troubles.

Additionally, please get comfortable with Booleans as values.  First, the above routine can read simply

```
 return (side1 + side2 > side3) or (side1 + side3 > side2) or (side1 + side3 > side2)
```

Second, your call to this routine is over-done: call it once and check the value once:

```
 if isValid(side1, side2, side3):
     # Compute area
 else
     # Print error message
```

You don't need to compare the result against **True**: it already *has* a logic value.  Second, if you get to the **else** part, you are *guaranteed* that the function returned **False** -- no need to call a second time with the same data; no need to check against **False**.

---

AFTER OP EDIT:

```
if isValid(side1, side2, side3) == True:
```

should be simply

```
if isValid(side1, side2, side3):
```

Do *not* compare a Boolean value to a Boolean constant; this is a redundant check.  You already *have* a logic value returned from the function.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I will change that in my program now.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has many problems:

1. The logic of your `isValid` function is wrong. If *any* of those predicates separated by `or`'s is true, it will return `True`. So if sides are 1, 1, 1000, it gives `True`...you should probably return `False` there.

   As an aside, if you sorted the side lengths, you could also get away with a single comparison.
2. You're using `is` to check equality. `is` checks object identity, not equality. Do not do that. Instead:

   ```
   if isValid(...):
       ...
   else: # don't repeat isValid, it's a waste
       ...
   ```